# My html button cannot be clicked, even though I modified only its style

Tags: html, css, button

The code I have for my button in HTML is this simple

What causes the button to not be able to be clicked, even though it is of type button?

```css
.menubutton {
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}
```

```html
<button class="menubutton" style="position:absolute;left:10%" type="button"><b>Home</b></button>
```

Comment: Please add more information so we can assist you more. Meanwhile try adding z-index to the style, incase some object is covering the button.

Comment: How do you know it's not clickable? Did you try catching a onclick event?

Comment: Please select an answer if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button *is* able to be clicked, as demonstrated by the following event listener:

```js
document.querySelector(".menubutton").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("button was clicked!");
})
```

```css
.menubutton {
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}
```

```html
<button class="menubutton" style="position:absolute;left:10%" type="button"><b>Home</b></button>
```

You probably mean that the user can't tell it's a button. To improve this, add a hover effect and pointer cursor to the CSS:

```js
document.querySelector(".menubutton").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("button was clicked!");
})
```

```css
.menubutton {
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  
  /*  pointer on hover */
  cursor: pointer;
  /*  transition */
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

/*  hover event */
.menubutton:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<button class="menubutton" style="position:absolute;left:10%" type="button"><b>Home</b></button>
```

Read more about hover effects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover#:%7E:text=The%20%3Ahover%20CSS%20pseudo%2Dclass,the%20cursor%20(mouse%20pointer).) and transitions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Answer (score -2):

1. I don't think you need to add `type=button` on a button element.
2. You should add all the styles in the element in the `<style>` tag.

Using these changes, you should have:

**HTML**

```html
<button class="menubutton">
    <b>Home</b>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```html
<style>
    .menubutton {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10%;
        background-color: orange;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 20px 50px;
    }
</style>
```